# Calculate point's coordinates relative to rotation in 3D-space

Tags: coordinate-systems, 3d

I have a point "A" in 3D-space, let's say in coordinates (2, 3, -1). Then there's a point "B" which position is `A + (-1, 2, -1)`, so now it's `(2 + (-1), 3 + 2, -1 + (-1)) = (1, 5, -2)`. How do I calculate the position of B when A "rotates"? In 2D-plane this would be easy:

[image: 2d-rotation]

How do I do this in 3D-space? Any help would be appropriated.

Comment: How does $A$ rotate?

Comment: It's kinda hard to explain. Point B is always in specific distance of point A. Point B is like something in your hand; it's exactly in front of you (point A), and when you turn, it doesn't stay there, but it rotates with you. Hopefully this clarified.

Comment: So, does $A$ move on the surface of a vertical cone whose point is in the origin? (together with $A$ pointing outward)

Comment: apply the same transformation matrix to point B as you did for point A.